# git merge in case of restructuring

Tags: git, merge

I'm not sure how to continue for merging.

I have a main branch containing a feature (let's call the file Feature.java). Then I created a new branch from it to improve that feature. After the improvment was done, I realized that I would like to keep the old version of that feature and just mark it as deprecated. So I refactored my code to Feature2.java.
Git shows me that file now as 'new' and Feature.java as removed (at my new branch). I committed the newly created file. Fine.
But what should I do with the file marked as removed? If I commit that and merge that branch back to the main branch - would that remove my old feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you staged and committed both the removed file and the new file, Feature.java will be removed while doing the merge.

You can easily keep Feature.java by performing a `git checkout Feature.java`. This will restore the file, so `git status` will just show `Feature2.java` as being untracked. Commit that file and you will be fine later when you merge your feature branch into the mainline.

Comment: Feature.java is marked as a change ('deleted)' - but not yet commited
Feature2.java is already commited
This is fine then? What happens at the merge with that changed Feature.java (Of course, I commited changes during development for Feature.java)

Comment: If you modified Feature.java while you were developing on your feature branch, you need to undo these changes before performing the merge. Otherwise master will get the latest version of Feature.java that you had in the feature branch. Do a `git checkout master -- path/to/Feature.java` and commit that on the feature branch.

Comment: Another option is to do an interactive rebase on the feature branch and edit all commits touching Feature.java. The edits would have to undo the changes to Feature.java. This would be the cleanest solution because after that it would look as if you never touched Feature.java in the feature branch.

Comment: how would that interactive rebasing look like? I will read bits and piece to find out how to do that but maybe you can give me a useful hint.

Comment: I used the checkout (from main branch) solution as my commits contain changes of other files I wanted to keep. Thank you

Comment: The interactive rebase would allow you to edit all commits and amend them, in your case by resetting the changes just for Feature.java. You should definitely read up on interactive rebasing as it's a very powerful error-correction technique.